# Get filename from paths in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

HI guys i am trying to get the image/video filename from path

Here i have paths in my php variable like this from database

```
E:/xampp/htdocs/pes/new/movie.mp4
E:/xampp/htdocs/pes/new/flowers.jpg
```

And i am trying to get new/movie.mp4 or new/flowers.jpg from above paths and display it in img tag or video tag

```
 <img src="new/flowers.jpg" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
```

or

```
<video width="400" controls>
      <source src="new/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
      Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
 </video>
```

Can anyone help me how to do that

Thanks in advance

Comment: while storing in database use `file_name` instead of `full_path` then use `site_url()` in your src attr

Comment: it is storing flowers.jpg like this in my db then how can i get it in my src tag

Comment: do like this : `<img src="<?=site_url('new/'.$image); ?>"`  where `$image` is the column name from table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this will help you :**

Set your `base_url` in your `config.php`

```
$config['base_url']='http://localhost/pes/'
```

and ur image `src` should be like this :

```
<img src="<?=site_url('new/'.$image); ?>" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
```

Comment: if u talking about js code u can write, but for php use controller

Comment: no,i am just writing jquery setTimeout function in view file?is it ok to write like that

Comment: @hi pradeep i ned one help

Answer (score 1):

Try with `base_url()`. Set your base_url in config.php for example www.xyz.com/ Update your code like this:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url() ?>new/flowers.jpg" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
```

And video frame:

```
<video width="400" controls>
   <source src="<?php echo base_url() ?>new/movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
                        Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

If all paths are relative to **FCPATH**, `FCPATH = 'E:/xampp/htdocs/pes'`, you can use:

```
<img src="<?php echo base_url(str_replace(FCPATH, '', 'E:/xampp/htdocs/pes/new/flowers.jpg')) ?>" alt="Trulli" width="500" height="333">
```

or

```
<video width="400" controls>
    <source src="<?php echo base_url(str_replace(FCPATH, '', 'E:/xampp/htdocs/pes/new/movie.mp4')) ?>" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support HTML5 video.
</video>
```

Comment: hi i have one doubt may i ask

Comment: Sure, please ask

Comment: can you please check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609445/give-access-to-dahsboard-php-page-without-login-in-codeigniter

Comment: i am trying to access the dashboard page without logged in can you please tell me how to do that