# give access to dashboard.php page without login in CodeIgniter

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I am trying to give access to dashboard page.If users not logged in also they should be able to access that page.

Here is my .htaccess page

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /pes/

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

From my point of view, the .htaccess file should look like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /pes/

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

The access to dashboard must be checked in your main controller, depend on how you have designed the logic.
Also, the mapping of urls must be done in `application/config/routes.php` file

Comment: okay my default controller is login  $route['default_controller'] = 'Login';

Comment: The main application controller should be your default controller or one which will take care about wrong urls. The login controller should be accessed only if is required.

Comment: i didn't get what you are tellign excatly

Comment: got it byt removing this line from my controller      if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged')) { //

Answer (score 0):

I Have done by removing this line from my dashboard controller.

```
   public fucntion index()
{ 
    if (!$this->session->userdata('is_logged')) {
      //function code
    }
}
```